# Product list name parameter does not appear in report

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I have a Google Analytics Product List Performance report. I can see data there about:

(this sends through data layer)

> Product list view
>   Product list click
>   Product ads to card
>   Product checkouts

But I can't see Unique Purchases (this sends through the measurement protocol).
Which parameter in the measurement protocol (transaction) returns the Product list? What am I doing wrong?

I'm using this query:

```
method: POST  
https://www.google-analytics.com/collect

- v=1
- &t=pageview
- &tid=UA-XXXXXX-X
- &cid=XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX
- &dh=xxxxx.ru
- &dp=%2Fsuccess%2Fpurchase_id_XXXXXXXX
- &dt=RUB_xxxxxx
- &ni=1
- &uid=xxxxx
- &pa=purchase
- &ti=xxxxxxxx
- &tr=xxxx
- &cd13=xxxx
- &pr1id=xxxxxx_xxxxx
- &pr1nm=xxxxxxxx
- &pr1ca=xxxxxxxxxx
- &pr1pr=xx
- &pr1qt=x
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation the parameter for Productlists for actions  is PAL (short for "product action list") (there is also one for [product impressions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#il_nm)).

I haven't tried this, but as I understand the documentation you cannot send a PAL with the purchase action. The documentation for PAL says

> This is an additional parameter that can be sent when Product Action
>   is set to 'detail' or 'click'.

which suggests that the product must be added to a list via an click/detail action that happens before the purchase, and then the purchase will automatically attributed to that list.

Comment: Thank you, Eike.
So that is not measurement protocol falt.

What we send in data layer is

event: 'productClick',
  ecommerce: {
    click: {
      actionField: {list: 'Main'},
      products: [
        {
          name: 'set-stydiy-manikura-50', 
          id: 452656,
          price: '72674',
          category: 'Услуги/Красота/Маникюр',
          position: 4

Comment: and

- event: 'productDetail'
- ecommerce
- detail
- actionField: {list: 'Main'}
- products
- name
- id
- price
 - category:

Maybe i should add something